# Visual Basic - Performing an action on an object that has the focus

Tags: vb.net, focus

I'm trying to do something very simple:
Create a method that handles multiple `textbox.gotFocus()` events in my form.
The goal is to select all text when the focus is given to any of the textboxes.

I know I could create an if-else block that checks to see whether or not each textbox has the focus, and then if so, just do `textbox1.selectall()`, or `textbox2.selectall()`, etc.

Is there a quicker way to do this that I'm missing that would just do it all in one statement that uses something like `object.focused.selectall()`?  I know these aren't keywords in vb, but they're the best descriptive words I can think of to explain what I'm trying to do.

Any input is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is more complicated than you think. You would have to create an event to trigger the method that handles the textboxes focus. The easy way is to put as you said a selectAll() method in every textbox gotFocus event.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built in to do that, unless you inherit from the TextBox and call SelectAll in the OnEnter override method yourself.

If you have a lot of TextBox controls, you could just iterate over the collections and add the method yourself:

```
Public Sub New()
  InitializeComponent()

  Dim ctrls As New Stack(Of Control)
  ctrls.Push(Me)
  While ctrls.Count > 0
    Dim ctrl As Control = ctrls.Pop
    If ctrl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
      For Each c As Control In ctrl.Controls
        ctrls.Push(c)
      Next
    Else
      If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        AddHandler ctrl.Enter, Sub() DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).SelectAll()
      End If
    End If
  End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since textbox doesn't have a focus event, what you can do is set up one handler to handle all the textboxes' Enter event.

Enter Event Handler

```
Private Sub TextboxEnter(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)
    Dim FocusedTextbox As TextBox = DirectCast(Sender, TextBox)
    FocusedTextBox.SelectAll
End Sub
```

Add the handler for each textboxes' Enter event

```
For Each tb As TextBox in Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    AddHandler tb.Enter, AddressOf TextBoxEnter
Next
```

If you need to filter the textboxes, use a common name pattern and use a conditional to check for that pattern in the Name property.